# Show exposed sort by at the Header of view

Tags: views

Drupal 7, views-7.x-3.7.

I have a exposed sort by item in the exposed form block.

I wish to show the sort by item at the top of the view result page instead of in the exposed form block.

How to do that?

Thanks!